# Sub menus not showing in hierarchical

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have added a new custom menu but sub menus not showing in hierarchical.

I want to display animal and automotive categories under More.

Anyone can help me?

The page I need help with: bit.ly/2Dz5EWB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your sub-menu is opening on hovering `<div class="cat-menu">` this element.

You need to remove this kind of CSS.

There is one unique class in list item `.menu-item-has-children` which has `sub-menu` for categories.

You just need to set hover CSS for this list item like:

```
.cat-menu ul li.menu-item-has-children:hover .sub-menu{
   display:block;
}
```

`<ul class="sub-menu">` is inside the `<li class="menu-item-has-children">` this element so you need to set CSS like above code.

I hope this will be helpful for you.